# update nsmanagedobject core data iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to update a full NSManagedObject but every example I see updates the attributes of the resultant object. I want to reorder rows of the fetched data and save them into CoreData like this

```
func changePosition(source: Int, destiny: Int){
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    do {
        var results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

        var itemAux = results[destiny]
        results[destiny] = results[source]
        results[source] = itemAux
        do {
            try context.save()
        }catch{
            //Handle Error
        }

    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }

}
```

This is never saved
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you aware that your kind of swapping is completety useless because there is no specific order of objects in the Core Data database? That means the order of the `results` array will be changed indeed but there will be no change in the database.

Comment: I thought there was an order, and core data kept it, my mistake I have to redo my db with an index. thank you!

Comment: @PabloR. Make sure to answer your own question and mark it solved if you've found the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not useless as @vadian said because there is no specific order of objects in the Core Data database, can control the order with an index attribute